# c++ program to find total no of nodes

Tags: c++, binary-tree, nodes

Why am I getting a segmentation error?

```
int countLeaves(Node* root)
{
    if (root = NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    int left = countLeaves(root->left);
    int right = countLeaves(root->right);
    return 1 + left + right;
}
```

Comment: Typo. You're always assigning `NULL` to `root` in your first line which evaluates false.

Comment: Please check this link first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Do turn on compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `root=NULL` in the statement

```
if(root=NULL) { return 0; }
```

sets `root` to `NULL` and evaluated to `NULL` (assigned value).

`NULL` is treated as false, so `return 0;` is not executed and the execution preceeds to next statement.

The next statement is

```
int left = countLeaves(root->left);
```

Here `root`, which is set to `NULL`, is dereferenced and this will lead to Segmentation Fault.

Answer (score 2):

You want to compare root to null, use `if(root == NULL)`